# Require Js - Seeking Hybrid implementation of the requirejs in "Not fully client side application"

Tags: javascript, requirejs

It has been couple of days that I am exploring the requirejs ( the JavaScript module loader for loading the modules and dependencies asynchronously).

What I have understood is you need to have all your JavaScript libs or plugins (like Jquery etc) to be loaded in the require.config for their uses as the dependency in any custom module you create or any other plugin you use which is directly dependent on jquery or any other lib.

What I am not sure and is skeptical about is if it can be used in the already built application where I only want few of my plugins or libs which are dependent on Jquery to be defined/used using requirejs and other application javascript continue using the jquery in its row form.

That is to say: I include the jquery using the script tag and not through the require.config but wish to use and include other plugin/JavaScript using require js which are dependent on Jquery.

In short, i want a kind of hybrid implementation of the requirejs in my already built server side application which is not a fully client side application.

A code snippet or how-to would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, provided you are careful about what you do.

All the `script` elements that load JavaScript code on which the code loaded with RequireJS depends should appear **before** any code that initiates a module load with RequireJS. This is the only way to ensure that what you need is available when RequireJS starts loading modules.

Then you have the option of have the modules loaded with RequireJS just assume that what is loaded with `script` has made itself available in the global scope and use it without adding it to your dependencies. For instance, if a module needs jQuery and it was already loaded with a `script` element, then the module would assume that `$` is defined already:

```
define(function () {
    $("p").append(...);
});
```

For 3rd-party code that has already listed dependencies on code that you happen to load with `script` elements, or if you prefer to make dependencies in code you write explicit, you have to use "glue modules". (**This is the option I prefer for my own code.**) The same module above would formally require jQuery:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $("p").append(...);
});
```

and you would have to have a "glue module" for `jquery`. I typically place such modules just before my `require.config` call *instead* of putting them in separate files. It would be something like:

```
define('jquery', function () {
    return $;
});
```

Note that the first parameter to the `define` call here is a string (rather than an array) which tells RequireJS the module is named `jquery`. You typically should not hardcode names like this but for glue modules, that's fine. The glue module makes the assumption that `$` is defined and is jQuery. Any module that needs jQuery depends on this module. If at a later stage jQuery is loaded as a RequireJS module, then the glue module can be removed and none of the modules that depend on jQuery need to be modified.

Comment: Thanks louis ... let me try the way you have explained here and will get back to you here